# Check if two stacks are equal in O(1) space

Tags: data-structures, stack

I was asked this in an interview:

Check if given two stacks are equal (size and order of elements) using O(1) space.

Stacks should maintain their earlier state (order of elements).

Recursion uses stack space so not valid.

One of my friend suggested to use String variable and append elements from one stack into it and push popped to the other one and then push from S2(old elements of S1) to S1 and do the same thing with S2. But this depends on the size of the Stack as String will grow depending on the size of stack.

Comment: It won't be enough just to pop from both of the stacks and compare the poped items until one of the stacks is empty? If any pair is not equal they are not equal

Comment: Stacks should maintain their initial state, but here stacks will be in different state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recursion *vs* iteration is not the issue here. The issue is how to leave the stacks intact, because the only way to inspect a stack in full is to empty it.

So what you need to do is store the popped members onto temporary stacks. This does not change the overall space requirements, since you only push onto the temporary stack objects that are popped elsewhere, and thus you are satisfying the O(1) spare requirement.

Here’s the pseudocode for an iterative solution:

```
function stacks_are_equal
  precondition: stacks s1, s2

  set equal? to true

  while s1 is not empty and s2 is not empty
    pop x from s1
    pop y from s2
    push x onto temp1
    push y onto temp2

    if x ≠ y then
      set equal? to false
      break out of loop

  if s1 is not empty or s2 is not empty set equal? to false

  while temp1 is not empty
    pop x from temp1
    pop y from temp2
    push x onto s1
    push y onto s2

  return equal?
```

And here’s the recursive solution:

```
function stacks_are_equal(s1, s2)
  if s1 is empty and s2 is empty return true
  if s1 is empty or s2 is empty return false

  pop x from s1
  pop y from s2

  empty? := x = y and stacks_are_equal(s1, s2)

  push x onto s1
  push y onto s2

  return empty?
```

Comment: Hey, If we look at it in this way, Recursion should also be a valid solution as that keeps the values of stack in recursive stacks ?

Comment: "...since you only push onto the temporary stack objects that are popped elsewhere, and thus you are satisfying the O(1) space requirement." -- Maybe. If the stack is implemented as a linked list, that's true. But if the stack is implemented as an array, then popping an item from the stack doesn't reduce the memory used by the stack. And the recursive version cannot possibly be O(1) space. Stack frames aren't free. If the lists are sufficiently large, you will run out of stack space.

Comment: @JimMischel Let me tackle these points separately, starting with the last: Just because the stack may overflow does *not* mean the algorithm isn’t O(1). For the purpose of asymptotic space analysis we do not assume any limits (put differently, we assume infinite resources). Stack space is not special in this regard: An in-place sorting algorithm (= O(1)) might likewise crash if your input array is too big to fit into main memory. And you can always make the call stack bigger. These are *physical* limits and while they’re relevant in practice, they’re immaterial for asymptotic analysis.

Comment: @JimMischel Your first point similarly confuses interface and implementation. “Stack” is an *abstract* data type. But a rigorous specification of this ADT will generally specify that a stack requires asymptotic, amortised space in O(n); that is, we may ignore its actual space requirement in asymptotic analysis. *In practice* it may be convenient to store the data in a fixed-sized array *as long as* we know that  actual usage won’t exceed this storage. If it does, we have violated the contract imposed by the ADT. This does not invalidate our asymptotic analysis; rather, it’s a “bug”.

Comment: @JimMischel As always, asymptotic analysis is a *theoretical* analysis that (intentionally) ignores physical constraints. In reality we have no unlimited resources, no infinite Turing tape. Space and runtime are limited by the number of atoms in the Universe, and entropy, respectively. Just as we can’t paint a physical, infinite number line, so we can’t feed limitless data to an O(1) algorithm. But this renders neither the concept of mathematical infinity nor asymptotic analysis invalid.

Comment: But the amount of stack space used by the recursive algorithm is O(n). Unless we assume a theoretical machine that can do recursion without a stack frame, I maintain that the recursive algorithm cannot possibly be O(1) space.

Comment: @JimMischel The *call stack* is O(n). But the *total memory* stays constant, because the stack only grows by the same amount that the input decreases by. The exact same is true for the iterative solution, in fact: it requires the exact same amount of memory as the recursive solution. The only difference is that the temporary stack is explicit, rather than being implicit via the call stack.

Answer (score 2):

Use recursion...Here is an example using java.

```java
private static boolean equalhelper(Stack<Integer> s1, Stack<Integer> s2)
{
    if(s1.isEmpty() && s2.isEmpty())
        return true;
    if(s1.isEmpty() || s2.isEmpty())
        return false;       

    Integer a=s1.pop();
    Integer b=s2.pop();
    if(!a.equals(b))
    {
        s1.push(a);
        s2.push(b);
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        boolean check= equalhelper( s1, s2);
        s1.push(a);
        s2.push(b);
        return check;
    }
}
```

Comment: This method works (almost! — you need to replace `a != b` with `! a.equals(b)`) but it’s doing *a lot* of redundant work. If you remove the unnecessary redundancy you can cut the size almost in half.

Comment: Thanks for the update.Made some edits.Actually Java has unboxing that's why a!=b even works.But made the edits and redundant codes removed

Comment: The unboxing is tricking you, because equality comparison is *not* performing unboxing! It tests regular reference equality. It will work *sometimes* because Java caches some values, but it won’t work in general. Try it: `Integer a = 1; Integer b = new Integer(1); a.equals(b);` — this will yield `false`! Similarly, `Integer a = 325125; Integer b = 325125; a.equals(b);` will also yield `false`.

Comment: Do this with two identical lists of 1 million items each. You will get a stack overflow error. So there's no way this is O(1) space.